# netbeans build folder: why does it fill up recursively?

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04

I was having a problem with netbeans experiencing crazy delays  doing the background scanning and classpath scanning. After installing a fresh netbeans 12, I loaded the project from usb, and it ran correctly, once. Before the run, the build folder contained 961 items. Unfortunately, after running it once, the build folder had over 20,000 items in it (this number varies: last try it was 7,849.)  This prevented running a second time, because the background & classpath scans had to handle that huge folder (I presume). I can repeat this: load the clean project from usb, see the build folder with 961 items, run the program successfully once, then see the build folder with way too many items. The mechanism of this huge number is: at first, before the damage, there exists in the build folder a single folder "classes", containing exactly what you would expect, namely, the package folders for the project. At this stage, there is no "build" folder in the "classes" folder. After the damage, there IS a build folder in the classes folder, and that build folder contains a classes folder, which contains all the packages AND another build folder. Apparently this is recursive, and is different each time - the difference being how many build/classes folders you have to go through before you get to a classes folder that doesn't have its own, extra, build folder. Obviously I need to prevent this recursive copying of the build/classes folders when the project runs. This was in fact the original problem - that project's build folder contained over 120,000 items. If I move the first extra build folder to trash, the program executes again correctly, but then the build folder again is radically expanded. All the same things happen on another machine, also with a fresh install of netbeans12.*************** I have just received an explanation, but not a solution (yet) from another friendly user. I don't know what to do next.

outside input----------------------------

this looks like a project setup problem like the “classes” folder is part of the resources.

So the build will take the last build result as resources for the new build. I would search for the settings in “Project Settings”

Right click on the project in the project explorer and choose “Project Properties”.

Some where you will find the “classes” folder as part of the build …

end outside input------------------------

Unfortunately I can't find anything called "classes" as part of the build settings, and I can't find anything like "project settings" but project "properties"

Comment: a relevant bug report exists: 88476

Comment: How do you change the project root, and what should it be set to, and can you do this on an existing project?